# How to add one month to month and year

Tags: oracle

I am working in oracle and new to coding and new to this site so I apologize in advance for the newbie question:

I have a script I am trying to run that will return the sum of next months' sales orders and compare that figure against our budgeted sales forecast. It was working great last month (November) when I set it up but now that it's December, I believe it's having problems figuring out that next month is a new year.

Essentially I  just want to sum of our sales order records from the next month and compare that number against our forecast number.

Here is what I have so far (I'm sure I am making lots of grammatical mistakes so please be patient!)

```
select
   "Backlog", "Forecast Amount" , round("Backlog"/"Forecast Amount",4) as "Backlog Percent"

from
    (select round(sum(NVL(unit_price,0) *NVL( ship_quan,0)),2) as "Backlog"

    from v_backlog_releases

where
    (TO_CHAR(V_BACKLOG_RELEASES.PROMISE_DATE,'MM\YYYY') = TO_CHAR(sysdate,'MM\YYYY')+1)),

    (select budamount as "Forecast Amount"

    from
       glbudget,
       glperiods

      where
        glbudget.glperiods_id=glperiods.id and
        TO_CHAR(GLPERIODS.START_DATE,'MM') = TO_CHAR(sysdate,'MM')+1)
```

The system won't let me post images of the output since I am too new. Essentially I should get something that looks like this:

Backlog | Forecast Amount | Backlog Percent

100,000 | 200,000         | .50

The backlog column is just a sum of ship quantities * price for all orders due to ship the following month.

Comment: I am not getting any errors but if I remove the "+1" from both date lines I get this months orders against this months forecast. It works great. When this script ran in November (with the "+1") it worked perfectly and gave me Decembers sales orders against Decembers forecast. Thank you for you response. I will try to upload a desired output and some sample info.

Comment: I did lots of research and I actually had tried that. When I change to TO_CHAR(GLPERIODS.START_DATE,'MM') = add_months(sysdate,1)

Comment: ...sorry, when I change to the above, I get General SQL error.
ORA-01840: input value not long enough for date format

Comment: I moved my comments to an answer.  Give it a try and comment below my answer if you continue to have problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that for December `TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'MM') + 1` is returning 13 instead of 1 of the next year. Obviously there is no month 13...

Try using `ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, 1)` instead and handle that result as appropriate. Best advice is to handle dates as dates instead of chars whenever possible.

Update based on comments:

Try using:

```
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM GLPERIODS.START_DATE) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, 1))
```

Documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/functions045.htm

Comment: OMG you are a genius. I have been beating my head against a wall for two days. Thank you!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @MarkStevens My pleasure.  Please accept this as your answer if this helped you.